# canvas not selectable on all area in starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

see 
http://liveweave.com/CQJDKc

when you click on back part of image ie image with girl and boys running u waill not be able to drag or select canvas group , but when u clik on sun part canvas is selectable and can be dragged.

but once u select canvas element and drag it whole canvas becomes selectable why so starngle issue could not figure out ??..

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/ImageCollection/StaticContent/image1_%20164248809.jpg', function (img) {
        var img1 = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        fabric.Image.fromURL('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Aurora_as_seen_by_IMAGE.PNG', function (img) {
            var img2 = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            group = new fabric.Group([img1, img2], {
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center'
            });
            canvas.add(group);
            group.center();
            //group.hasRotatingPoint=true;
            //group.lockMovementX = group.lockMovementY = true;
            group.lockUniScaling = true;
            group.hasBorders = group.hasControls= false;
            //group.selectable = false;
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this exactly is causing your problem, but I think your problem is just because you are positioning the group to the center, and the canvas does not render it nicely.

Removing the group from canvas after positioning it to center and then again adding the group to the canvas solves your problem.
here is demo http://liveweave.com/lcCAFH

```
 canvas.add(group);
                group.center();
              canvas.remove(group);
              canvas.add(group);
```

hope this helps

Comment: no need to do this i just added group.scale(1); it works fine see http://liveweave.com/A5RljT why so ??..some issue with .center() ??

Comment: why scale, group is already defined, you can remove or add groups whenever you want, why to make complex `scale(1)` operation with no results, can you tell me why scale(1) works.

Comment: i donot know what's problem why canvas is not getting renderred after group.center();

Comment: According to me even if you can solve the issue with scale(1), you should not do this, you can stick to  my solution till you find the cause of the issue, it is just because adding and removing group is not that intensive task as scaling.. Finally its up to you